# Problema con PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema con mi phpmyadmin, y es que por mucho que intente editar su archivo config.ini, le cambie los puertos o haya desinstalado Mysql server para evitar que choquen con el Mysql que ya trae por defecto mi xammp, no hay manera de que logre acceder a my phpmyadmin. Y es bastante raro, porque, si tengo el puerto 3306 establecido, me sale estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, lo mas extraño de todo, es que si en el config.ini, cambio mi puerto a 3307, si que logro acceder al phpmyadmin, pero sin pedirme contraseña, ni nombre de usuario, y los datos de la sesión están vacíos. No consigo dar con la solución correcta para regresar a mi phpmyadmin a la normalidad y que me inicie sesión como siempre, pidiéndome la contraseña y nombre de usuario ¿conocéis alguna solución a este problema?. Uso un sistema operativo de windows y utilizo el xammp, no se si cambiarlo por el wammp o el lammp, solucionaria algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes validar el puerto! a ver si otra aplicacion lo esta utilizando? con el comando `netstat -aon`

Comment: `...destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión`. Quiere decir que el MySQL instalado no tiene permisos para ser accedido desde el cliente, esto puede ser por permisos denegados en la base de datos o el usuario y/o contraseña no están correctos. Al parecer el MySQL del Xampp si entra bien. Intenta poner `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` a ver si entra con autenticación manual.

Comment: Perfecto, con eso he logrado arreglar el problema de que no me pide usuario y contraseña. Consigo entrar con el usuario root sin ningún tipo de problema, pero en el xammp tengo un nombre de usuario y contraseña por defecto, el cual al introducirlo, "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'Edward'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", ¿Debo quizas cambiar algo en mi config.ini? ¿o añadir algo mas en el archivo config.inc.php?

Comment: Puedes tener 2 phpmyadmin, si no quieres tener en 2 puertos distintos, [descarga el zip](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) y descomprimelo en la raiz de `htdocs` y renombra el directorio a `phpmyadmin2` o como quieras (que no se llame igual al original), luego renombra el archivo `config.sample.inc.php` a `config.inc.php`. Deja el parámetro `...['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` para que también pida usuario/contraseña. Lo que no estoy seguro es si tendrás que abrir cada phpmyadmin en un navegador diferente si quieres ambos a la vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto, una vez que conseguí acceder a phpmyadmin con mi usuario root, en el apartado de cuentas de usuario cree una nueva cuenta de usuario y contraseña con la que poder acceder con ella. He realizado de nuevo comprobaciones a los archivos config.ini, y el archivo config de php, todo esta en orden, así como de nuevo instale el mysql server sin ningún tipo de problema.